# Camel consuming from specific Kafka partition

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, kafka-consumer-api

Can someone advise if the kafka-camel could consume message from a specific partition from kakfa topic.

I want to consume a message from specific partition from topic using Camel Kafka component, I have seen consumer options here http://camel.apache.org/kafka.html, but could not see any option for this.

I could do it for producing message to specific partition, just by setting header values.But same thing unable to do it while consuming.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be more specific what you mean? And have you seen the docs at https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-kafka/src/main/docs/kafka-component.adoc